# What happens if the president refuses to sign an approved law?

Tags: legislature, israel

In Israel, every law approved by the Knesset is signed by the president, the prime minister, and the Knesset chairman. Suppose one of these three (e.g. the president) disagrees with the law and refuses to sign.

Is the law still considered valid? Are the citizens and the courts expected to obey it? I though of two options:

- The law is considered valid, as the president's signature is just a formality.
- The president can be forced to sign the law (e.g. by criminal charge), but until he does, the law is invalid.

Which of these options, if any, is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The [received opinion](https://knesset.gov.il/constitution/ConstP5_eng.htm) (November 9 and 23, 2003) under Israeli law is your option 1, under Article 11 §(a)1, which states that "The President of the State shall sign every law, other than laws relating to his
powers". The Basic Laws do not give the president veto power over laws. Those were different days, so perhaps the interpretation of the law will have to be decided by the Supreme Court, though the [status is the judiciary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Israeli_judicial_reform) in deciding legal matters is itself controversial. No current law speaks against the traditional position that the president's signature is symbolic.

Comment: The discussion at the first link in this answer is somewhat ambiguous and identifies at least one counterexample. It appears to me that the question is not definitively resolved.